# Is session_unset() deprecated?

Tags: php, session

In the PHP documentation for [`session_unset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php) there is no hint that this function is deprecated so I think it's fine to use it. But then I read through the documentation about [`session_destroy()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) where I found this hint:

> **Note:**
>       Only use session_unset() for older deprecated code that does not use $_SESSION.

I know that the `session_unset()` function is an equivalent for `$_SESSION = array();`. So what should I use now? Why is on one site a hint that this function is deprecated but on the other hand in the documentation about the function itselfs there is not deprecated note. What's the truth about this function now?

Comment: There is a notice `Note:

    If $_SESSION (or $HTTP_SESSION_VARS for PHP 4.0.6 or less) is used, use unset() to unregister a session variable, i.e. unset ($_SESSION['varname']);.`, they just didn't use the word `deprecated` but that's what they meant to say with that note.

Comment: Well bit `session_unset()` unsets all data stored in $_SESSION while `unset()` just unsets one array entry of `$_SESSION`.

Comment: *"`Only use session_unset() for older deprecated code that does not use $_SESSION`"* - Meaning, that one of the deprecated functions is [`session_register()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php)

Comment: Looks like an oversight to me: if `session_unset()` only unsets "registered" session variables, then it cannot be useful in PHP >5.4.0, since `session_register()` has been removed. If that is *not* what it does, then the manual page is in dire need of a rewrite.

Comment: @IMSoP Well `session_register('foo', 'bar')` is an equivalent for `$_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar';` but `session_unset()` is like `$_SESSION = array();` So it does unset all the session data whereas `session_register()` just registers a new key-value-pair.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the exact reason, too, but it can be found here I guess: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/session/session.c

PHP handles variables in `ZVAL` pointers and I think they just wanted the `_SESSION` superglobal to be handled the same way as any other variable, and not with a "special" command `session_unset()`.

Another benefit is better garbage collection handling I think.

Sometimes, "deprecated" does not mean its a bad function, but you should not use it because code might be removed in future packages simply because it is not neccessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to close the session you must use [session_destroy()](http://php.net/session_destroy).

```
session_destroy();
```

If you want to clear the variables of the session you must use:

```
$_SESSION = array();
```

And if you want to clear only one variable of the session you must use:

```
unset($_SESSION['example']);
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. But Why shoudln't I use `session_unset()` anymore? I'm looking for the reason - why :-).

Comment: Because unset($_SESSION['example']); is enough ;)